# Oozie bundle with a properties file for each coordinator

Tags: file, properties, bundle, oozie

I have a scenario where multiple coordinators need to be run as a bundle. And the coordinators have same properties with different values. Bundling the coordinators means that i need to specify separate property names in the job.properties file.This means going back and renaming all the properties that are used  in the workflows.Is there a way around this.

Comment: I am afraid you need to do that. :(.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have 3 options:

1. Have your properties named differently which is the exact thing you are trying to avoid.
2. Have your properties named diffently in the bundle properties file but then rename them in the coordinator when passing them to the coordinators. That way you could at least use the same names for the parameters in the coordinators/workflows.

> ```
> <bundle-app name="bundle_name">
>  <coordinator name="coordinator 1">
>   <app-path>${coord1AppPath}</app-path>
>   <configuration>
>    <property>
>     <name>value1</name>
>     <value>${coordinator1_value1}</value>
>    </property>
>   </configuration>
>  </coordinator>
>  <coordinator name="coordinator 2">
>   <app-path>${coord2AppPath}</app-path>
>   <configuration>
>    <property>
>     <name>value1</name>
>     <value>${coordinator2_value1}</value>
>    </property>
>   </configuration>
>  </coordinator>
> </bundle-app>
> ```

3. Don't use a bundle. It might be easier to just not use a bundle alltogether but start each coordinator on its own, that way they can use 2 different property files.

I know that none of those options are optimal, but i can't think of any other possibilities.

Comment: Thanks @garkyn for the reply. I ended up not using the bundle because one single properties file was exploding.